# What does conda-build not like about this version number?

Tags: python, conda, ibm-watson, conda-build

Python / Anaconda newbie here. I am trying to work with packages and multiple environments.

Right now I'm trying to install the package "ibm_watson" which is available through PyPi. Here's the story so far:

```
conda skeleton pypi ibm_watson
```

This worked, but it generated a meta.yaml which conda-build didn't like. It had a version string ">=2.0," with an extraneous comma. I had to hand edit that out. Where is that error happening? Anyway, I got past that. Here's where I'm stuck now.

```
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform osx-64: {"python_dateutil[version='>=2.5.3']"}
```

OK, fine. It thinks I need a version of python_dateutil which is at least 2.5.3. But here's the problem:

```
> conda list | grep dateutil
python-dateutil   2.8.0    py37_0
```

It certainly seems to me as if 2.8.0 should satisfy the requirement of being more than 2.5.3. So what is causing this error and how do I get past it?

(Actually, I forgot. ibm_watson also had another dependency error, requiring ibm_cloud_sdk_core. So actually this particular error happened after trying to build THAT package. But also in the original build attempt for ibm_watson).

Comment: Isn't there a mismatch between `python-dateutil` and `python_dateutil`?

Comment: That was it! So I hand edited the meta.yaml _again_, and this time didn't get that error. But then I got more errors, about other dependencies that don't exist and also apparently come from PyPi.

Comment: I previously installed this package with pip, and it properly handled all the dependencies. But I understand mixing pip and conda is a bad idea, and it did create some issues already. So I backed out the pip install and decided I was going to try to make conda work. But what is the explanation why pip worked and conda didn't. Does it mean that the developers who posted the conda info at PyPi didn't debug properly?

Comment: Thank you for your sharp eyes. I now have only one conda-build error to resolve (at least so far) which I will ask about in a followup.